# install gcc-4.8.1 from source code on Ubuntu-16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc

I am trying to install gcc-4.8.1 from source code on Ubuntu-16.04 with gcc-5.4.0 already installed. However, when compiling the gcc source code, the following error occurs:

```
msgfmt: //gcc_install/build/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/src/.libs/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.55)
```

I googled but I can't find anything helpful. Can anyone give me some advice to handle this problem. Thanks!

Also, is there any to install gcc-4.8.1 with "sudo apt install". I tried this, but this got me the newest version of gcc-4.8.5, which is not what I need.

[gcc-4.8.1](/questions/tagged/gcc-4.8.1)

Answer (score 1):

gcc-4.8.1 : No easy workarounds for Ubuntu 16.04, I think.

But gcc-4.8.1 builds OK with Ubuntu 14.04 - 64 ....

```
cd build-gcc481/
../gcc-4.8.1/configure --prefix=/usr/local/gcc481 --program-suffix=481 --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-multilib --disable-libstdcxx-pch
```

Result : `gcc48-c++_4.8.1-ubuntu14_amd64.deb` https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNV3ZFR2JNRXE2b1k/view?usp=sharing ... Provides /usr/local/bin/{gcc48, g++48}

The package installs OK into Ubuntu 16.04, and the new compilers are working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

you can try open it https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libicuuc.so.36 , download libicuuc.so and install it

Comment: rpmfind. For Ubuntu. Awesome.