# Downgrade gcc/g++ in Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, gcc

I am trying to downgrade gcc/g++ to 4.8.1.  I tried two options, both with problems.

1. use `sudo apt install gcc-4.8 g++-4.8`.  This option will install 4.8.5 etc. I wonder if there is any way to specify 4.8.1. `sudo apt install gcc-4.8.1 g++-4.8.1` does not work as it will complain that *`"unable to locate package gcc-4.8.1"`*.
2. Download "gcc-4.8.1" and follow the official steps ("configure, make, make install") but it fails at the make step with errors "CXXABI_1.3.8" not found.

I found another solution but I am not sure whether it is desirable (" [install gcc-4.8.1 from source code on Ubuntu-16.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38417663/install-gcc-4-8-1-from-source-code-on-ubuntu-16-04)").

How do I downgrade gcc/g++ to 4.8.1 in Ubuntu?

Many thanks.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve exactly?

Comment: The compiler in our company is gcc/g++ 4.8.1 on ubuntu 13-04. My ubuntu is 16.04 and gcc/g++ is 5.4.0. I want to have the same compiler as the company's in order not to have issues related to ABI etc.  (I don't know much about gcc compilers and think this is the simplest way to work around).

Comment: http://semver.org/ - 4.8.5 should have the same behavior as 4.8.1, but better.

Comment: Thanks! I will try both options(using 4.8.5 and 4.8.1 build from the deb file).

Comment: In a way Offtopic but on the point: 13.04 is dead version from the beginning of 2014... if there is not a real serious reason to keep it alive I would suggest you to ask them do a fresh install (and choose an LTS that lasts 4 5 years... not like 13.04 that was for 9 months). If you use internet from these pc's you already have sequrity issues

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is a good point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do I downgrade gcc/g++ to 4.8.1 in Ubuntu?

I think you want look into the command "update-alternatives" (instead of 'downgrade').

To learn some more browse "https://askubuntu.com/questions/529687/how-to-use-update-alternatives-to-manage-multiple-installed-version-of-the-sam"

The update-alternatives works by changing what the command g++ points at. Currently on my system, g++ points to g++-6.

---

I have sometimes experienced an install that simply does not work.  My recent g++ v6.2 install is broken, I don't know why.

But because my ubuntu is out of date, I plan to upgrade to the latest ubuntu.  I might as well wait to install the latest compiler.

In the mean time I have 6.2.0, which does not 'work' (cause unknown).  g++ points to this:

```
~$ g++ --version 
g++ (GCC) 6.2.0
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Since I seldom remove (un-install) the previous version in use, it turns out that with a simple search to identify what is available, I can access an older compiler using a suffix.  For example

```
~$ g++-5 --version
g++-5 (Ubuntu 5.2.1-23ubuntu1~15.10) 5.2.1 20151028
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

So, I continue more or less the same as before the failed 6.2.0 install.

For you, I think this means that you can use your package manager to install your desired earlier compiler, but remember to search for it in case it already exists on your system.  Then use update-alternatives to make it the default, or just learn the new command name to invoke, i.e. g++-5, and continue developing with both commands easily available.